# Provide Inject not working properly in vue 3 composition API

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am working with Vue 3 composition api and am retrieving weather data via `async/await fetch` and I get a 200 response and the data in the request within the Chrome Dev Tools.

In the component receiving the data and making the call I have a `provide` method and then I am `inject`ing the data into another output component. The issue is in the `inject` component. The value for the `inject`ed variable is always null and does not update in the Vue Dev Tools so my data is never output to the screen. I went through the docs and the code is pretty much the same but I can't get it to work. Can anyone see an obvious issue?

Receiving Component

```js
setup () {
    async function getCurrentWeather () {
      const response = await fetch(`${baseWeatherApiUrl}q=${userInput.value}`);

      userInput.value = null;

      return weatherData.value = await response.json();
    }

    const returnedWeatherData = reactive(weatherData);

    provide('returnedWeatherData', returnedWeatherData);

    return {
      getCurrentWeather,
      userInput,
      weatherData
    }
  }
```

output component

```js
setup () {
    //Provide default of empty object in case no results exist
    const weatherData = inject('returnedWeatherData');

    console.log(weatherData) //No output even when making a new request to the weather api
    
    return {
      weatherData
    }
  }
```

As a separate test I tried to `provide/inject` hardcoded values found in the docs but still `geolocation` when injected remains null.

```js
provide('geolocation', {
      longitude: 90,
      latitude: 135
    })
```

```js
const userGeolocation = inject('geolocation')


    console.log(userGeolocation) // Nothing logged

    return {
      weatherData,
      userGeolocation
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `provide`-ed argument should be the `ref` itself (not wrapped in a `reactive()`):

```js
// Parent.vue
export default {
  setup () {
    const weatherData = ref()

    // ❌
    // const returnedWeatherData = reactive(weatherData);
    // provide('returnedWeatherData', returnedWeatherData);

    // ✅
    provide('returnedWeatherData', weatherData);
  }
}
```

And the child component's `console.log()` in `setup()` does not automatically get invoked again. You should wrap that call with [`watchEffect()`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/computed-watch-api.html#watcheffect) so that it does get called upon change to the `ref`:

```js
// Child.vue
import { inject, watchEffect } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup () {
    const weatherData = inject('returnedWeatherData')

    // ❌
    //console.log('new weatherData', weatherData.value)

    // ✅
    watchEffect(() => {
      console.log('new weatherData', weatherData.value)
    })
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-provide-reactive-data?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FWeatherData.vue)

Comment: It doesn't work in your example because you're using `provide`/`inject` incorrectly. The `provide`-ed value can only be `inject`-ed by a descendent component. Your example has `<weather-output>` as a *sibling* of `<weather-input>`, so `inject()` will not find the `provide`-ed `weatherData` from `<weather-input>`. See [fixup of your example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-provide-reactive-data-mkcwhu?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FWeatherOutput.vue).

Comment: thank you for looking through this. I had assumed that `provide/inject` was able to be used with sibling components as well as `parent/child` components but I was wrong. I learned something valuable. Thank you again!

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was importing `inject` from "*@vue/runtime-core*" instead of "*vue*".

Of course `provide` was imported from "*vue*".

Just leaving here, maybe it's gonna save someone an hour.